# Bind foreground color to control's IsEnabled state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, styles

I'm having trouble binding the label color on my Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonTab objects to their Enabled state.

I tried the following first:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonTab}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But it has no affect on the foreground. It looks like something in the ribbonTab library code is programatically overwriting the foreground.

I then tried this:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseRibbonTabStyle" TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonTab}">
    <EventSetter Event="IsEnabledChanged" Handler="RibbonTab_IsEnabledChanged" 
</Style>
```

```
private void RibbonTab_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if( (bool)e.NewValue == false )
       ((RibbonTab)sender).Foreground = (new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter()).ConvertFromString("Gray") as System.Windows.Media.Brush;
   else
       ((RibbonTab)sender).Foreground = (new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter()).ConvertFromString("White") as System.Windows.Media.Brush;
}
```

But that also failed with the following compile time error:

`System.Windows.UIElement.IsEnabledChanged="RibbonTab_IsEnabledChanged_Event" is not valid. 'IsEnabledChanged' must be a RoutedEvent registered with a name that ends with the keyword "Event".`

How can I get this to work?

Comment: That binding looks just broken to me, are you even in the context of a `ControlTemplate`? Do you know how `TemplatedParent` works? Are there [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a simple property trigger:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonTab}">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" /> 
 </Style>
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you, and I can't believe I didn't try this more simple method first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonTab}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

Comment: @H.B. Yes it is. I've moved the setter to after the trigger. I've seen that make a difference. Note that Steve's solution does the same thing.

Comment: I can see what you did; so far i have not seen any case where this would make a difference. If you can show me one i'd be very interested...